# Passing values to excel file does not give the new calculated values by excel

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, xlsx, exceljs

I have an excel file which does some complex logic calculation on input of values into the cells. I wrote a javascript node app to pass the input values and read the output but it seems like the excel does not do the calculation and give the new values. Is this do-able by some other approach? I have a time constraint for converting all the excel formula logic to javascript so thought of doing that.

Comment: let me see if i got it right... your excel already have formulas and they aren't updating theys values when you insert data via javascript?

Comment: you got it right. @dot.Py

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `Calculation Method` is set to `manual`.

To change this to `automatic`:

- **2003:** Tools > Options > Calculation > Calculation > Automatic.
- **2007:** Office button > Excel options > Formulas > Workbook Calculation > Automatic.
- **2010/2013:** File > Options > Formulas > Workbook Calculation > Automatic.

Or you can find a way to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to refresh your calculations.

Comment: doesn't help @dot.Py